# Date range logic for past dates

Tags: javascript

I have 3 dates: `Present`, `Start` and `End`.

Present date = '11/21/2018' (today's date)

Start = '10/5/2015'

End = '12/4/2019

I need to create a daterange using these dates.

[image]

I have the following code to calculate date range.

```js
function createLedger(stDate, etDate) {

  if (stDate && etDate) {
    var endOfLeaseDate = moment(etDate, "MM/DD/YYYY");
    var startOfLeaseDate = moment(stDate, "MM/DD/YYYY");
    dateRange(startOfLeaseDate, endOfLeaseDate);
  }
}

function dateRange(stDate, etDate) {
  var dates = [];

  var now = stDate.clone();
  var day = stDate.date();

  while(now.isBefore(etDate)) {
    //deal with variable month end days
    var monthEnd = now.clone().endOf("month");
    if (now.date() < day && day <= monthEnd.date()) { now.date(day); }

    dates.push(now.format("YYYY-MM-DD"));
    now = now.clone().add({ "months" : 1 });
  }
  console.log(dates);
}

function RunLedgerAndPV() {
  var pDate = "11/21/2018" 
  var stDate = "10/5/2015";
  var etDate = "12/4/2019";
  createLedger(stDate, etDate);
}
RunLedgerAndPV();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js"></script>
```

I need to edit this in a way where the date ranges from Present date to enddate instead of StartDate but the range itself is based on the day of startdate.

Any help is appreciated! Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing the following worked for me. I created a new date using start 'day' and present month and year and created an array using that day instead.

```
            var pastDT = stDate.getUTCDate();
            var pastMT = pDate.getUTCMonth()+2;
            var pastYR = pDT.getUTCFullYear();
            var LedgerDT = pastMT + '/' + pastDT + '/' + pastYR;

            var pastStart = presentDate > startDate;

            if (startDate && pastStart){
                var stDate = moment.utc(new Date(LedgerDT)).format("MM/DD/YYYY");
            }

            else if (startDate && !pastStart)
                var stDate = moment.utc(new Date(presentDate)).format("MM/DD/YYYY");

            var etDate = moment.utc(new Date(endDate)).format("MM/DD/YYYY");
            createLedger(stDate, etDate);
```

Answer (score 0):

You only need to assign today's date (formatted) to pDate.

```
function RunLedgerAndPV() {
    var now = new Date();
    var nowMonth = ("0" + now.getMonth()).slice(-2);
    var nowDate  = ("0" + now.getDate()).slice(-2);
    var nowYear  = now.getFullYear();

    // "11/21/2018"
    var pDate =  nowMonth + '/' + nowDate + '/' + nowYear;
    console.log(pDate);

    var stDate = "10/5/2015";
    var etDate = "12/4/2019";
    createLedger(pDate, etDate);
}
```